# Configure, extend Grafana Docker container

Tags: docker, configuration, dockerfile, grafana, provisioning

I want to use Grafana as a dashboard for time series data from a Prometheus DB. To this end, I'd like to deploy it as Docker container that connects to the Prometheus container.

Instead of configuring Grafana through the GUI *after* starting it, I'd like to setup a custom Grafana container that is pre-configured to directly connect to the Prometheus data source and show a custom dashboard. I want to have all necessary files in a GitHub repo and then just call `docker run ...` to start the custom Grafana container.

I read the docs on [Docker deployment](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/), [configuration](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/), and [provisioning](http://docs.grafana.org/administration/provisioning/), but since I'm still quite new to Docker and haven't used Grafana before, I'm not sure how to apply these instructions to my Grafana container. How do I get started?

I suppose, I'll have to write a custom `Dockerfile` that uses Grafana as base image and then copies some configuration files into the Docker container? But which files do I need to copy where?

Comment: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/

Comment: I'm aware of this doc (see link in question), but I couldn't find answers on how to configure dashboards, data sources etc. Again, I'd prefer to do everything file-based, eg, through a custom `Dockerfile` rather than through endless env. vars. that I need to set when calling `docker run`.
So do the paths [here](http://docs.grafana.org/administration/provisioning/) refer to where the config files are expected *within* the Docker?

Comment: Ah, didnt follow your links, sorry. You just create all your configuration files, put them along with Dockerfile and use `COPY/ADD` in your `Dockerfile` to load this config into container